# Group of outlets suddenly out

Tags: electrical, receptacle

5 outlets in a row suddenly went out. Breaker isn’t tripped, gfi isn’t tripped. I’ve checked for loose wire and don’t see any. Pulled receptacles of jbox and not showing any current on wires connected to them. Outlets on other side of basement including outs 6 feet away from the ones not working are working.

Comment: Are any of the outlets using the back stabs/push in connections or are they all using the screws?   Turn off the breaker and see what else goes off.  The problem might be there.  Or you might have mice.

Comment: Thank you ! They are screw terminal on the sides. Turn off the breaker and just a light fixture and a couple other , working outlets go out.

Comment: Do not know how your house is wired, but usually it goes from the panel to the closest device(outlet/light) to next.  I expect the problem will be at or between the last working device to the first non working device.

Comment: Are you sure there is no other breaker somewhere...

Comment: Are any of them a GFCI? Those can totally fail.

Comment: POWER must be OFF. You can use an ohm-meter and measure from box to box to determine where the open is.

Comment: Odds are the dead outlet closest to the panel is the first one in the line of dead outlets (as crip659 suggests).  Are you getting no power to either of the cables attached to that outlet?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the outlet that is in line just before the ones that went out. That's the one where the connection is loose.

Comment: No none are gfi, I check both of the good ones on each end of the bad and I do t see any loose wires. I think I’ll replace them all and see what I get.